# Issue Pulling Back Ratings

Tags: beatsmusic

I am trying to pull back ratings from a user but am getting 401 unauthorized:

Request:

```
GET https://partner.api.beatsmusic.com/v1/api/users/<VALID USER ID RETREIVED USING ME ENDPOINT>/ratings?&offset=0&limit=20&access_token=<VALID ACCESS TOKEN USED TO GET USER ID> HTTP/1.1
Host: partner.api.beatsmusic.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Content-Type: text/xml
Date: Mon, 14 Jul 2014 01:29:54 GMT
Server: Mashery Proxy
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="partner.api.beatsmusic.com", error="invalid_token"
X-Mashery-Error-Code: ERR_403_NOT_AUTHORIZED
X-Mashery-Responder: prod-j-worker-us-west-1b-19.mashery.com
Content-Length: 23
Connection: keep-alive

<h1>Not Authorized</h1>
```

The access token is viable since I am able to use it to get other resources.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about access tokens for a third-party web site.

Comment: I is not about the access token.  It is about the fact that the API is not behaving as expected.  This is actually the process Beats Music has for their API.  They push people into stackoverflow and if it appears to be specific to the user they pull in the issue into ZenDesk.

Comment: Forgive me, but if their site is returning a message suggesting your token is invalid, then it's a problem with your token. Either your token is invalid or their web site is broken. [so] is focussed on software development issues and there's nothing we can do about a third-part site's security regime. If you're suggesting you might have a problem with your code then you need to post some and indicate where you think the problem is and why. Otherwise, you should take this back to [tag:beatsmusic]

Comment: It could be the way I am structuring my requests.  I am leaning toward it being their service, but it could be something I am doing.  I will follow up with them as well and if it turns out to be something I am doing wrong I will post what I was doing wrong so others can learn from it.  If not, something with their service it can be posted and they will also be able to learn about it.

Answer (score 1):

We were able to replace values in your URL and receive ratings. This is also a standard format: https://partner.api.beatsmusic.com/v1/api/users/[USERID]/ratings?access_token=[TOKEN]

Comment: We are making a change to the API. Ratings should be working, as expected, shortly.